# Protect CSS-layout for overlaying div like addthis.com

Tags: css, inheritance

I have an overlaying div (much like addthis.com) that I want to protect from inheriting styles. I have looked at reset-css files such as Blueprint but this tends to screw up the parent styles as well.

For instance:

User has `div { border-right:1px solid red; }`
This is appended to all divs on the page, including my overlay. Of course I can write `#mydiv { border-right:0; }` but doing this for all css-properties is massive. There could be an easier way?

PS. I am not in an iframe, and the parent page is dynamic, could be any URL really DS.

Comment: I can't tell exactly what you mean. Could you provide a code sample or link?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this might fix your overlay div.

```
div#myoverlay {border-right:0;}
```

Comment: ´div#myoverlay´ would protect me from border-right properties, but what about all hundreds of properties that are possible? 

is there not a better way to reset css for 1 element (being my overlay)

Comment: Unfortunately, if you want to reset all the properties for this one element, you'll have to put all the attributes into the CSS for Myoverlay.